# Bootstrap label and jquery-validate text overlaping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would need some assistance with my form validation. Basically, I am using Bootstrap 4 with MDB for Bootstrap.

Now, the problem is, every time I try validating a field the label text, which holds the name of the input field, goes up when the input field is active, and if there is an error, the error text overlaps with the label. I've attached a few screenshots for better understanding of the problem.
Any help would be appreciated.

[Img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wWRx.png)

[Img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEsNr.png)

Here is my html, css and js for the form

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var emailInput = $('#email');
  var nameInput = $("#username");
  var pass = $('#password');

//Validate email address
  emailInput.keyup(function() {

    var email = $('#email');
    var expression = /^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    var regex = new RegExp(expression);

    if(emailInput.val() == '' || !(emailInput.val()).match(regex)) {
      emailInput.addClass('validate');

      return false;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  });

//Validate name
  nameInput.click(function() {

    var expression = "^[\\p{L} .'-]+$";
    var regex = new RegExp(expression);

    if(nameInput.val() == '' || !(nameInput.val()).match(regex)) {
      nameInput.addClass('validate');
      return false;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  });

/*
//Validate password
/ pass.click(function() {
    var expression = "^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$";
    var regex = new RegExp(expression);

    if(pass.val() = '') {
      alert('error');
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  });*/


  $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
      email: {
        required: true,
        email:true
      },
        password: "required",
    },
    messages: {
      email: {
        required: 'Please enter an email address.',
        email: 'Invalid email address'
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #292c2f;
}

.card {
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.card-block {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 12px 24px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 12px 24px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 24px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
  background-color: #292c2f
}

.form-header,h3 {
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #DDD;
}

hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}

i {
  color: #FFF;
}

.loginLabel {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #CCC;
}

.linkLogin,
.linkLogin:focus,
.linkLogin:visited {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.linkLogin:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

i.fa.fa-user.user1 {
  color: #FFF;
}

i.fa.fa-user,
i.fa.fa-envelope,
i.fa.fa-lock {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

i.fa.fa-user.active,
i.fa.fa-envelope.active,
i.fa.fa-lock.active {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

input[type=date]:focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=datetime-local]:focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=email]:focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=number]:focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=password]:focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=search-md]:focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=search]:focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=tel]:focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=text]:focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=time]:focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=url]:focus:not([readonly]),
textarea.md-textarea:focus:not([readonly]) {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!-- REIGISTRATION FORM -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <div class="card">

        <form method="post" id="form">
          <div class="card-block">

            <!--Header-->
            <div class="form-header">
              <h3><i class="fa fa-user user1"></i> Register</h3>
              </div>

              <!--Body-->
              <div class="md-form form-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i>
                <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control">
                <label for="username">Name</label>

              </div>
              <div class="md-form form-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix"></i>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
                <label for="email" id="em">Email</label>
              </div>

              <div class="md-form form-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-lock prefix"></i>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
              </div>

              <div class="md-form form-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-lock prefix"></i>
                <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" class="form-control">
                <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
              </div>

              <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-elegant" id="signUp">Sign up</button>
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                  <label class="loginLabel">Already have an account? <br /><a href="signin.html" class="linkLogin">Sign in</a></label>
                </fieldset>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at Bootstrap's internal validation: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_inputs2.asp, you can pass in a `.has-error` into your `form-control class` when validation returns false. Hard for me to troubleshoot because it always fires my Chrome HTML5 validator, which looks fine btw

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll have a look and report back.